# Page Templates not using functions.php

Tags: templates, wp-enqueue-style

I am having an issue with page templates in Wordpress. I have created some for my website but they are not using the wp_enqueue_style in my functions.php.

anybody know why this is? mainly my stylesheet is in functions.php so i want it to use the same one

Comment: Do your templates include the `wp_head()` and `wp_footer()` functions?

Comment: I believe I do but I don't think it is in the head tag as said below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your enqueued css should work for all page template if there is no condition applied. could you please share it how you enqueued?

Another thing you can check. In header.php, can you please check that wp_head(); function has been called properly in the page template's head tag. if not exists in the header.php between the head tag then add this function.

Thanks.

Comment: Thank you for your help it appears some templates did not have wp_head(); when putting this in the <head> tag it worked

Comment: Make sure you also have `wp_footer()` in the footer, before the closing `</body>` tag. Some scripts won't work if you don't.